# ClassCastException while executing "HelloWorld" applet code

Tags: java

I am trying to run simple "Hello world" java applet program. But on execution applet does not appear in browser instead ClassNotFoundException occurs.

This is how I am accessing it from browser:-

`<applet width="500" height="50" codebase="http://localhost:13383/tuexample/" 
    code="dk.certificate.demo.DemoApplet.class" >...applet..</applet>`

JavaCode:-

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class DemoApplet extends Applet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Welcome in Java Applet.",40,20);
    }
}
```

Exception Log:-

```
Java Plug-in 10.21.2.11
Using JRE version 1.7.0_21-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\rahil_khan
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
28-May-2013 14:20:51 <INFO> thread applet-dk.pbs.applet.bootstrap.BootApplet-1 - stop
28-May-2013 14:20:51 <INFO> thread applet-dk.pbs.applet.bootstrap.BootApplet-1 -  
destroy
```

Comment: Please show the details of the exception.

Comment: @RahilKhan We need the logged details of the exception.

Comment: what is your `webapp` directory structure ? Looks like you are not adhering to your directory structure.

Comment: This is the only log which I get. There is no exception mentioned. Is it possible to run applet in JRE 1.7?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi It is dynamic web project. Cannot add image.

Comment: You are running your *applet* in a server environment. We need your `webapp` directory structure.

Comment: I am running applet directly from my eclipse.
Server:- Tomcat 7

Webapp structure:-
    `
    WebContent> META-INF
    WebContent> variant4>login.jsp
    WebContent> WEB-INF>classes
    WebContent> WEB-INF>lib
    WebContent> WEB-INF>web.xml
    WebContent> index.jsp
    `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let me finally answer this Question:**

You are getting `ClassNotFoundException` because Applet class, it seems, can not be found in the configuration you have provided.

**Your code does this:** It is trying to find `DemoApplet.class` inside the package `dk.certificate.demo` inside the `localhost:13383/tuexample/`

So, if we consider `localhost:13383/tuexample/` to be your root *webapp* directory called `xyz` then your possible file structure should be like this:

`XYZ/dk/certificate/demo/DemoApplet.class` which clearly does not seem to be the case.

Also make sure you have `package dk.certificate.demo` inside your class file which I don't see at the moment.

Now, it should be easy to fix your code from what I have explained.

Answer (score 0):

In tag:

```
code="dk/certificate/demo/DemoApplet.class"
```

- `package dk.certificate.demo;`?
- dk/certificate/demo/DemoApplet.class?

By the way `JApplet`, swing i.o. AWT, is the better solution.

---

Maybe in your case the code base resides in (should be) WEB-INF/classes, which normally is notokay, as WEB-INF files should not be accessible by URL.

In fact normally a .jar is created in a separate project and deposited in the Web Contents directory.

Comment: why `/` ? `Dot.` is perfectly valid too.

Comment: can you use `/` ? never seen before.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I seem to remember the dot to be valid too, but then the ".class" irritated me. Slash I have seen.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, package is "package dk.certificate.demo;" and class location is "dk/certificate/demo/DemoApplet.class".

Comment: I will try by creating jar and and adding it to web contents directory.

Answer (score 0):

@RaviTrivedi and @JoopEggen thanks for your support I was able to fix the problem.

Two solutions:-

1. DemoApplet.jar:-
   I created jar(***DemoApplet.jar***) of my applet code(***DemoApplet.java***) and
   placed it in ***AppletDemo\WebContent\lib*** folder.
2. I moved classes folder 
       from ***AppletDemo\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes***
       to   ***AppletDemo\WebContent\classes***

And from login.jsp I made call to applet in following way:-

```
    <!-- DemoApplet.jar -->
<applet 
    width="500" 
    height="50" 
    codebase="http://localhost:8080/AppletDemo" 
    archive="lib/demoApplet.jar"
    code=dk.certificate.demo.DemoApplet.class >...applet..</applet>

     <!-- classes -->
 <applet 
    width="500" 
    height="50" 
    codebase="http://localhost:8080/AppletDemo/classes"
    code=dk.certificate.demo.DemoApplet.class >...class...applet..</applet>
```

It worked both ways.
Thanks a lot. :D